# Groff -ms .R macro not working; Can't format heading

Tags: text-processing, pdf, groff

groff version: 1.22.4

My style guide insists on formatting headings following way:

- Level 1 **UPPERCASE BOLD 12pt**
- Level 2 ***Bold italic letters 10pt***
- Level 3 *Italic letters 10pt*

According to reference for groff **.R** macro is supposed to
behave as **.B**, but makes font regular instead of bold, but every time i use it I get blank line, although **.BI** and **.I** works. How am to supposed to manipulate text format for headings when even if **.I** works but not for **.NH** for which it makes only text italic but not number.
example ms file:

```
..NH 1
.LG
Heading 1
.PP
Text 1
.NH 2
.I
.LG
Heading 2
.PP
text 2
.NH 3
.R Heading 3
.PP
Text 3
```

Output:

[image: Output picture]

Commands that I use to generate pdf:

```bash
preconv -e utf-8 rest.ms | refer -P -p ./bibliography | groff -wall -b -mec -Tdvi -ms > rest.dvi
dvipdfm -cz 9 rest.dvi
```

I use these commands bc of this: [What's the simplest way to process files with UTF-8 characters in groff on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/341829)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the macro definition (eg on my Linux machine it's in `/usr/share/groff/1.22.4/tmac/s.tmac`) I see

```
.de R
.ft R
..
```

Clearly that's just setting the font; it doesn't take any parameters!

If you add a line to the start of your document.

```
.par*define-font-macro R R
```

then .R will act the same as .B but with Roman font.

Note that there's no space between arguments so ".R Heading 3" displays "Heading3", same as ".B Heading 4" would show "Heading4"

You may be better off using the non-argument version of the macros; e.g.

```
.NH 3
.R
Heading 3
.PP
Text 3
.NH 4
.B
Heading 4
.PP
Text 4
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use this line at the start of my document, although it doesn't change the fact that numbering will still be in bold font, how can I make it so from level 3 onwards numbering and text in heading will be in regular font?

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, this is more of a bug in AT&T *ms* and its documentation than anything else.

In section "Emphasis" of Lesk's "Typing Documents on the Unix System" (1978) document, which is the de facto spec of the *ms* macro package, `R` is presented alongside `B` and `I`, noting that the latter two can be used not just to switch fonts when used without arguments, but to set a lone argument in a different typeface.  The `B` and `I` macros of *ms* in Seventh Edition Unix (1979) supported a second argument as a suffix in the current font, but the manual wasn't updated to mention this.

In 1990, GNU *ms* added support for a third argument, a prefix in the current font.  But still, through *groff* 1.22.4, the `R` macro did as Stephen Harris pointed out.

*groff* 1.23.0 has fixed this; [the font-switching macros behave consistently and orthogonally](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/tmac/s.tmac?h=1.23.0#n1575).  The [man page](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/tmac/groff_ms.7.man?h=1.23.0#n1085) has been updated to document this, and 1.23.0 has [an entire manual for the *ms* package](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/groff.git/tree/doc/ms.ms?h=1.23.0).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I figured out that i can just use \fR and \fP

Comment: That works, albeit less well with spell checkers.  You might also consider the _groff_-style escape sequences \f[R] and \f[], which _do_ work better with spell checkers.

Comment: Ok, but how should i go about making numbering regular aswell?